# Javascript - modifying global variable inside function

Tags: javascript

I am having an issue modifying a global variable from inside a function. From what I understand, not only should `direction` be what I set it inside the function, but it should also retain that value in the global scope, too, but it doesn't.

Consider the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var direction;
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#players_previous a').on('click', function() {direction = 'prev'; console.log(direction);});
    $('#players_next a').on('click', function() {direction = 'next'; console.log(direction);});
  });
</script>
```

When the buttons are clicked, `console.log();` returns `undefined`. If I try to access `direction` from Chrome Developer Tools Console it returns `undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That should work, can you make a working example using JSFiddle or SO code snippets?

Comment: Yes, give me a moment.

Comment: The var datatype can only guess what the required datatype should be, without specifying you can end up with all kinds of parser errors. What should it be?

Comment: @KyleT Umm, WAT? JavaScript doesn't really have data types.

Comment: @KyleT Parser errors in JavaScript? JS isn't strongly typed.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_datatypes.asp What i mean to say is that var does not specify one specific type

Comment: @KyleT—variables don't have types at all, only values do.

Comment: @KyleT—please don't read w3schools, that reference is completely wrong, it has at least two glaring errors.

Comment: I've tried `var direction = ''` to no success. It works just fine in JSFiddle. Something must be wrong elsewhere in my code.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work just fine. The problem was elsewhere in my code. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x6q5do83/)

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li id="players_previous"><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
    <li id="players_next"><a href="#">Next</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
var direction;
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#players_previous a').on('click', function () {
    direction = 'prev';
    alert(direction);
  });
  $('#players_next a').on('click', function () {
    direction = 'next';
    alert(direction);
  });
});
```